# Array Index Out Of Range- Swift

Tags: swift

I was creating a ToDoList App in Swift and it worked perfectly about three days ago but when I came back to the computer, I got this error message. Fatal Error: Array Index Out Of Range. Could someone tell me how to fix this.

```
import UIKit

var date = [String]()

var todoItem = [String]()

class SwiftController: UIViewController{


@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return date.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->UITableViewCell{


    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")




    cell.textLabel!.text = date[indexPath.row]

    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = todoItem[indexPath.row]


    return cell
}


func tableView(tableView:UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
    {
        todoItem.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        date.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)


        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(todoItem, forKey: "ToDoItem ")


        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(date, forKey: "ToDoDate")

        table.reloadData()

    }
}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    if
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("date") != nil{

            date = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("date") as! [String]

    }

    if
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ToDoDate") != nil{

            date = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ToDoDate") as! [String]
    }





    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: Don't just give us a huge chunk of code. Narrow it down to the problematic areas.

Comment: and do you know what line of code is causing the error to fire?

Comment: Ya, sorry for the confusion. The specific line of code that had the issue was the cell.detailTextLabel!.text = todoItem[indexPath.row]

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the project?

Comment: Your viewDidLoad populates the `date` array, but nothing populates `todoItem`.

Comment: check to todoItem count may be row populaiton is based on  date . so if the count of todoIte is less than date it will show error.

Comment: Yes, thank you Michael I forgot to populate the todoItem. Thanks, everyone for the help.